# targeting XML data via DOM child nodes

Tags: javascript, ajax

if I have an XML object that looks like:

```
<book id="01">
  <author>Conner, Jim</author>
  <title>House Hunter</title>
  <genre>DIY</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect describes his theories 
    on finding best value homes.</description>
</book>
```

I can access the author property with:

```
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book')[0].firstChild.nextSibling
```

and the title property with:

```
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book')[0].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling
```

...etc... I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to get this data via JQuery but I'm curious as to whether or not it can be done more efficiently using vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Author
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book')[0].getElementsByTagName('author')[0]

Author - text only
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book')[0].getElementsByTagName('author')[0].firstChild.data

Title
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book')[0].getElementsByTagName('title')[0]

Title - text only 
request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('book')[0].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.data
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hgb3g/1/)

Comment: didn't think to use getElementsByTagName again. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Have fun :)